# Kerning feedback on logo

Tags: typography, critique, kerning

I'm kerning this simple 'logo' for an online magazine/blog and since I'm not completely sure if I've 'got it' I would appreciate some help from any kern masters here. I've zoomed out and flipped it but have doubts.

My focus is mostly on the distance between the I and the N - just not sure if it's too big of a gap or just my head playing games with me.

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I don't particularly see the problem in the separation between I and N, I see it in the others, especially in the angled corners.

---

Taking the separation between the two vertical strokes as the reference module (`a` in the image below), you can make a base scheme that can be optically adjusted later:

[image]

From there, the relationship between a curved and straight stroke and between a straight stroke and a vertex can share the same distance, in this example `2/3 a`:

[image]

If you want a tighter kerning, change the `a` measure and adjust the others proportionally

[image]

---

This is the comparison in a reduction between the question logo at the top and the one of this answer to better appreciate the difference:

[image]

Comment: Glad to help...